# std::map, std::unordered_map - narrowing conversion in initializer list

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

Is it bug or standart permits it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int,int> mm {{44,44}, {33.3, 54}, {222.2,222.2}};
    for(auto& [f,s] :mm) {
        std::cout<<f<<" - "<<s<<std::endl;
    }

    std::map<int,int> m {{44,44}, {33.3, 54}, {222.2,222.2}};
    for(auto& [f,s] :m) {
       std::cout<<f<<" - "<<s<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Test it on [wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DldMYuGVwvS8R7vU) with clang10 and gcc10. There is not such problem with `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: Unrelated, but wandbox has a `share` button. You can type in the code and share it directly.

Comment: To clarify: You expect a "narrowing conversion" error here but there is none. Correct?

Comment: Can you add the code with std::set too?

Comment: std::set<int> l{1,3,4.5,7.9}; // Narrowing
https://wandbox.org/permlink/vsXdjiS8YUHMzOfN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The element type of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` is [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). The problem is that `std::pair` has a templated constructor,

> ```
> template< class U1, class U2 >
> constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
> ```
>
> Initializes `first` with `std::forward<U1>(x)` and `second` with
>   `std::forward<U2>(y)`.

E.g. given `{33.3, 54}`, `U1` is deduced as `double` and `U2` is deduced as `int`, note that this is an exact match and no conversions are required for this constructor to be used to construct the `std::pair`, then no narrowing conversion happens either.

On the other hand, for `std::set`, given `std::set<int> s {33.3};`, the constructor of `std::set` taking `std::initializer_list<int>` will be used, and the `std::initializer_list<int>` is initialized from `{33.3}`, narrow conversion happens.